# Azure CDN font loading issue

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-webassembly, azure-cdn

I have deployed the Blazor Web Assembly (ASP.Net Core Hosted) to Azure Web App then i have enabled the CDN (Standard Akamai pricing tier) for that Web App (Networking > Azure CDN). All the static asssets like JS, CSS, Images are loading from the CDN except fonts. It says CORS orgin error for CDN endpoint. I have also tried adding mime type in web.config file of he Azure Web App but no luck.
Can anyone help to resolve this issue.

Screenshot:

[image: Azure CDN .woff Font error]

Comment: Can you share the detailed URL (please hide/remove your CDN endpoint name in the URL) and error message? So that we can help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: Hi @Fei Han, Thanks for your response. Please find the updated question with screenshot

Comment: Does the font file is stored under Blazor wasm project `wwwroot\fonts` folder?

Comment: @Fei Han - sorry for the delay. It was worked after enabling Allow Cross Origin in Web App

Answer (score 0):

Answering this as it might help others with similar queries:

[CORS support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#add-cors-functionality) is built-in for Azure App Service. You can configure CORS [via the Azure portal](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript.md#-how-to-configure-cors-in-azure-app-service) by navigating to your App Service, selecting CORS under the API section on the left blade, and specifying the origins that should be allowed to make cross-origin calls. To allow all, use "*" and remove all other origins from the list.

To enable CORS via Azure CLI, use the [az webapp cors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/cors?view=azure-cli-latest) command as follows:

```
az webapp cors add --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --allowed-origins "['*']"
```

Refer to [this](https://sibeeshvenu.medium.com/azure-cdn-with-azure-web-app-access-to-font-at-cdn-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-a3ce0e9e014a) blog post for a detailed walkthrough.